# How can I group multiple columns in a hierachy with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Here is a Demo Model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

And this the code I have so far:

```
//Some sample data
var fooList = new List<Foo> {
    new Foo { SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(0), SomeValue = 1 },
    new Foo { SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(0), SomeValue = 2 },
    new Foo { SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6), SomeValue = 3 },
    new Foo { SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6), SomeValue = 4 },
    new Foo { SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12), SomeValue = 5 },
    new Foo { SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12), SomeValue = 6 },
    new Foo { SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(14), SomeValue = 7 },
    new Foo { SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(14), SomeValue = 8 }
};

//The query
var result = from foo in fooList
             group foo by new { foo.SomeDate.Year, foo.SomeDate.Month } into g
             select new
             {
                 //This should be the parent
                 TheYear = g.Key.Year,

                 //This should be the content
                 TheMonth = g.Key.Month,
                 TheSum = g.Sum(e=>e.SomeValue)
             };
```

This gives me something like this:

```
[0] = { TheYear = 2016, TheMonth = 3, TheSum = 3 }
[1] = { TheYear = 2016, TheMonth = 9, TheSum = 7 }
```

What I am trying to do, is getting every year combined, so I have a list of Years, which contain something like this:

```
[0] = {
    TheYear = 2016
    TheContent = {
       [0] = { TheMonth = 3, TheSum = 3 },
       [1] = { TheMonth = 9, TheSum = 7 },
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to apply `GroupBy` twice in the hierarchy, first by `Year` ant then on `Month`.

This should work for you.

```
fooList.GroupBy(g=> new { g.SomeDate.Year })
       .Select(s=> 
            new 
            {
                Year = s.Key, 
                TheContent = s.GroupBy(x=>x.SomeDate.Month)
                            .Select(m=> 
                            new 
                            { 
                                Month =  m.Key, 
                                TheSum = m.Sum(e=>e.SomeValue)
                            }).ToList()
            });
```

Check working [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u61OEo)